# Bash script to find which server is missing from the file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, scripting

Im relatively new to BASH scripting. I was hoping someone could help. I have two files. File 1 is a .csv file that contains certain server attributes.

cmdb_ci_linux_server.csv

```
"CLS000","csl000","Linux SuSe","9","HP"
"CLS001","cls001","Linux SuSe","9","VMware, Inc."
"CLS002","cls002","Linux Red Hat","5.11","VMware, Inc."
...
"VSRQ1CS1","vrsq1cs1","Linux SuSe","11","VMware, Inc."
```

These are servers that have been checked out. I need to compare it to the list of all the servers, and find out which ones havent been checked. The list of all the servers is in this format:
hosts.txt

```
cls000
cls001
cls002
cls003
cls004
cls005
...
cls499
```

I have tried a few different scripts, none have worked for me. I tried to do all the various steps in seperate scripts, hoping I could keeps things relatively simple. This one makes sense to me, but it would not return anything. Any help is much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read name host_name os os_version manufacturer
do
cat cmdb_ci_linux_server.csv

cat hosts.txt

grep -vf cmdb_ci_linux_server.csv hosts.txt

done
```

I know my way around linux, but not very well. Im much more familiar with windows. I was kinda thrown into this job unexpectedly :/

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That snippet is a bit confused. It appears to be a few attempts at the problem all mushed together. That `read` command is being given no input though so it will just "hang" until you give it some by typing or hit ctrl-c to kill it or ctrl-d to end the input. That `grep` command is the right idea but needs an input file of *just* the names that have been checked to work not the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
(cat cmdb_ci_linux_server.csv | 
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print substr($2,2,length($2)-2)}'|
 sort | uniq;
 cat hosts.txt | sort | uniq) | sort | uniq -c
```

example result:

> 1 cls000
>
> 2 cls001
>
> 2 cls002
>
> 1 cls003
>
> 1 cls004
>
> 1 cls005
>
> 1 csl000

left number: indicates the number of occurrences found

Comment: I got the same output. So if its a 1, it is only in one file, so I can assume its one of the missing servers? And if its a two, it was found in both files? Is that correct?

Comment: @ChrisAllison That's right , I edited the post to be so

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
while  read line
do
IFS=","
arr=($line)
text=${arr[1]//\"/""}
[[ $(grep $text hosts.txt -c) -le 0 ]] && echo "$text: Not Matched"
done <cmdb_ci_linux_server.csv
```

Comment: I ran this, and every single instance in my cmdb_ci_linux_server.csv said Not Matched.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the strings all contain double quotation, while in hosts.txt they don't. I have edited it to tackle that.